# How to play a local video on Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, mediacontroller

As my splash screen for my application I have chosen to use a video. I have made sure that the video is properlly formatted (according to android media format guidelines) so that is not the issue. The issue I am having is in getting the path to the local video file (the video is in res/raw/video.mp4). I am getting the error "Can't play this video" when I attempt to play the video. The code I am using to play the video is

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);

    String str = "R.raw.video.mp4";
    videoView.setVideoPath(str);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

with the xml purely containing a linear layout with a videoview inside of it.

This is my first time dealing with android video so any help would be appretiated